# TikZ: How to set the plotmarks to the foreground

Tags: tikz-pgf

Sometimes I have some plotmarks and some lines *later*. So the marks becomes unnice.

How can I say something like: "every mark to the foreground"?

*Note that I do not want to set the `\coordinate`s to the foreground (they where used just for the example) or maybe some other tricks.  I really want to know, how to set the plotmarks to the foreground.*

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
Mark/.style={ mark=*, mark size=1.5pt, mark options={fill=yellow} },
]
\coordinate[](A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[](B) at (2,3);
\coordinate[](C) at (1,1);


\foreach \P in {A,B,C}{
\draw[]  plot[Mark]  coordinates{(\P)};
}

\draw[] (A) -- (B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three possible solutions:

- draw lines on background layer, with the `tikz` library `backgrounds` loaded,
- draw marks on foreground layer, with the option `on above layer` from package `tikz-layers` used, and
- draw filled circles as `\node`s, then the overlapping is auto avoided (see `pgfmanual` v3.1.7a, sec. 17.11 *Connecting Nodes: Using Nodes as Coordinates*).

```tex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  Mark/.style={ mark=*, mark size=1.5pt, mark options={fill=yellow} },
]
  \coordinate[](A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[](B) at (2,3);
  \coordinate[](C) at (1,1);
  
  \foreach \P in {A,B,C}{
    \draw[]  plot[Mark]  coordinates{(\P)};
  }
  
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \draw[] (A) -- (B) -- (C);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

```tex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{tikz-layers}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  Mark/.style={ mark=*, mark size=1.5pt, mark options={fill=yellow} },
]
  \coordinate[](A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[](B) at (2,3);
  \coordinate[](C) at (1,1);
  
  \begin{scope}[on above layer]
    \foreach \P in {A,B,C}{
      \draw[]  plot[Mark]  coordinates{(\P)};
    }
  \end{scope}
  
  \draw[] (A) -- (B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

```tex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{tikz-layers}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  Mark/.style={ circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3pt, fill=yellow },
]
  \node[Mark] (A) at (0,0) {};
  \node[Mark] (B) at (2,3) {};
  \node[Mark] (C) at (1,1) {};
  
  \draw[] (A) -- (B) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

All three ways give the same output
[image]

Moreover, if you have many coordinates to link one-by-one, then

- `\draw[mark=*, ...] plot coordinates {(0,0) (2,3) (1,1)};`
- or even `pgfplots`
  might help;

Comment: Ah, ok. TYVM, good answer to this question. I have a new idea, similar to this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575252/tikz-how-to-use-draw-options-only-for-coordinates-which-exists