# TikZ: How to use draw options only for coordinates which exists / foreach-problem

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have some coordinates  (say A, B, C).

Now I make sth. like this: `\foreach \P in {A,B,C} \draw[fill=pink]  (\P) circle[radius=2.5pt];`

If I would have said `\foreach \P in {A,B,C,X} \draw[fill=pink]  (\P) circle[radius=2.5pt];`

I would have got the error `No shape named 'X' is known.`

So my question is:  How could I have sth. like the symbolic code

```
\ifcoordinateexist 
\draw[fill=pink]  (\P) circle[radius=2.5pt];
\else % nothing
\fi
```

I there a simple solution, maybe with TikZ-tools?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\coordinate[label=A](A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=B](B) at (2,3);
\coordinate[label=C](C) at (1,1);

% Will work:
\foreach \P in {A,B,C} \draw[fill=pink]  (\P) circle[radius=2.5pt]; 


%% Will not work:
%\foreach \P in {A,B,C,X} \draw[fill=pink]  (\P) circle[radius=2.5pt]; 
% ---------> No shape named `X' is known.
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in [my previous comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575252/tikz-how-to-use-draw-options-only-for-coordinates-which-exists-foreach-proble/575253?noredirect=1#comment1448680_575253),

> tikz nodes are defined globally (also mentioned in [Martin Scharrer's original answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37713)), so if there is a node `X` defined in previous tikzpicture(s), then this test (the `\ifcoorddefined` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575253)) would fail.

Here is an enhanced tester `\ifNodeDefined{<node name>}{<true>}{<false>}` which can test whether the given node is defined in the current `pgfpicure`, an environment internally used by `tikzpicture`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\long\def\ifcoorddefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}

\def\ifNodeDefined#1{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{\@secondoftwo}{%
      \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@pi@#1\endcsname\pgfpictureid
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate[label=X] (X) at (1,0);
  \coordinate[label=Y] (Y) at (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0pt]
  \coordinate[label=A] (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[label=B] (B) at (2,3);
  \coordinate[label=C] (C) at (1,1);
  
  \foreach \P in {A,B,C, X, Y, L, M}{
    \ifcoorddefined{\P}
      {\draw[fill=pink] (\P) circle[radius=2pt];}
      {}
  }
  \node[anchor=north] at (1,-.5) {old tester};
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0pt]
  \coordinate[label=A] (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[label=B] (B) at (2,3);
  \coordinate[label=C] (C) at (1,1);
  
  \foreach \P in {A,B,C, X, Y, L, M}{
    \ifNodeDefined{\P}
      {\draw[fill=pink] (\P) circle[radius=2pt];}
      {}
  }
  \node[anchor=north] at (1,-.5) {new tester};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution here:   https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85531/46023

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\long\def\ifcoorddefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\coordinate[label=A](A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=B](B) at (2,3);
\coordinate[label=C](C) at (1,1);

\foreach \P in {A,B,C, X, Y, L, M}{
  \ifcoorddefined{\P}{  \draw[fill=pink] (\P) circle[radius=2pt];  }{}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 some comments: i) `coordinate` is a kind of specialized nodes, so naming the `\ifXXX` with `\ifNodeDefined` is better. ii) tikz nodes are defined globally (also mentioned in [Martin Scharrer's original answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37713)), so if there is a node `X` defined in previous tikzpicture(s), then this test would fail.

Comment: Ok, thx. ..... ;)

Comment: @ muzimuzhi Z    If you want, you could create an else-function and post it as an answer. That could be interesting.

Comment: I'm wondering how to assign a distinct count to every `tikzpicture` which be used to assign a distinct internal macro to every node. This will take some time since I'm not familiar with the node implementations yet.

Comment: I added a missing empty argument to use of `\ifcoorddefined`.